# Undefined Variable within class

Tags: php, class, variables

I recently made a class in PHP
I am trying to declare a variable within class and using str_replace in a function but its show undefined variable

```
class Status{
  $words = array(".com",".net",".co.uk",".tk","co.cc");
  $replace = " ";
  function getRoomName($roomlink)
    {
      echo str_replace($words,$replace,$roomlink);

    }
}
$status = new Status;
echo $status->getRoomName("http://darsekarbala.com/azadari/");
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated thanks you

Comment: `echo str_replace($this->words,$this->replace,$roomlink);`

Comment: Read this http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php. Start with the introduction but read all the way through to atleast The Basics. You will spot your mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Your variables in the function `getRoomname()` aren't adressed properly. Your syntax assumes the variables are either declared within the function or passed while calling the function (which they aren't).

To do this within a class, do it while using `$this->`, like this:

```
function getRoomName($roomlink)
{
    echo str_replace($this->words,$this->replace,$roomlink);
}
```

For further informations, please have a look into [this page of the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Answer (score 0):

*Maybe because of the version or something, when I tested your exact code, I got `syntax error, unexpected '$words' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)`, so setting your variables to `private` or `public` should fix this one.*

About the `undefined varible`, you have to use `$this->` to access them from your class. Take a look:

```
class Status{
    private $words = array(".com",".net",".co.uk",".tk","co.cc"); // changed
    private $replace = " "; // changed
    function getRoomName($roomlink){
        echo str_replace($this->words, $this->replace, $roomlink); // changed
    }
}
$status = new Status;
echo $status->getRoomName("http://darsekarbala.com/azadari/");
```

Also, since `getRoomName` isn't returning anything, echoing it doesn't do much. You could just:
`$status->getRoomName("http://darsekarbala.com/azadari/");`.

or change to :
`return str_replace($this->words, $this->replace, $roomlink);`